# adding time and date to datetime in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to add date and time to a datetime field in mysql database using PHP.

My datetime in mysql database is stored like this:

```
2015-01-20 05:10:17
```

I tried to add 5 days to that field like this:

```
$Date = date();
$end_date = date("Y, n, j, G, i, s", strtotime($Date. ' + 5 days'));

UPDATE myTable SET end_date='$end_date' WHERE randKey='$id'
```

but when I look at the database for updates I see the `end_date` field like this:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

which means it has been updated but everything has been set to 0 for some reason!

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
$end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). ' + 5 days'));
```

MySql store the datetime in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the real runtime difference between your solution and mine is that your solution includes a single extra string concatenation, which for something that is probably not high-throughput production code, is of trivial concern. I'd say that either solution should work pretty much identically.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to add the five days to the current date in one string, using the two parameters to `strtotime` would be much easier, as so:

```
$Date = date();
$end_date = date("Y, n, j, G, i, s", strtotime('+5 days', $Date));
```

The second parameter specifies what the "current" time is; that is, where to base the +5 days off of (start position). When unspecified, it defaults to `time()`.

Answer (score 1):

First, the code you provided doesn't add 5 days to the value of the field, but five days to today's date. See, if your field contains 2015-01-01 and as you wrote, you would like to add 5 days to this field, you shouldn't add five days in PHP to date() because it will be 2015-01-25 instead of 2015-01-06. So if you want to add 5 days to the field value use this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET end_date=DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 5 DAY) WHERE randKey='$id';
```

But if you want to add five days after today, use this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET end_date=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) WHERE randKey='$id';
```

If you care for the time also, not just the date, use `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()`.

I hope it helps.